# How do you use Core Location without User sharing/granting permission?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-location

I have implemented core location in my app.

Everything works perfect when user allows sharing the location at start of the app.
But when user does not share his location "South atlantic" is shown in the location field in the app.

What should be done to avoid this and what should be displayed when the user does not share his location.

I am using this code for getting the location:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude]; //insert your coordinates

    [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation: loc completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
         //String to hold address
         locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
         NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);
         //Print the location to console
         NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
     }];


    return YES;
}



- (NSString *)deviceLocation
{
    NSString *theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return theLocation;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9) for information on how to get the user's location. Bottom line, you have to create the [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) location manager (like you are), but then start a location service (either the low-power significant-change location service or the standard location service) and wait for the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124) method [`didUpdateLocations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a) to return a location (or for [`didFailWithError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidFailWithError%3a) to report an error, either because the app failed authorization, or because the device couldn't satisfy the location request for some reason). You can't, though, just grab the location from the `CLLocationManager`. You have to wait for the service to call `didUpdateLocations` before you reliably start using longitudes and latitudes.

The [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9) will walk you through all of this, including some very helpful code samples.

Comment: @user1837938 I now realize that your question was how to do this without asking for permission, which I failed to answer. Apple's app submission guidelines (see section 4) explicitly prohibit that practice. There are ways you can do it, but I think it's infinitely better to ask for permission than to be caught doing it surreptitiously.

Answer (score 4):

You can check `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` to verify that the user has allowed location services using something like

```
int result = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
```

It has return values in

```
typedef enum {
    kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```